# Which normal input socket should I use when I have a mix between shaders?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, normals

Since we have the option to use normal maps in Cycles via the normal input socket, this question frequently pops in my head:

In the simplest mix, diffuse and glossy, should I connect the normal map to the diffuse or the glossy shader?

What about other shader mixes?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. you can plug it in to either one, it depends on what you want.

Comment: The easiest solution is to try it yourself and see which one (or all) produces the result you want. It's part of the process of creating the material.

Comment: Well.. Julian answered to my question already. But you are right, I should have done some testing before. Now I did it and will add to Julian answer. Thank you both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to give the **whole material** a structured surface, put it into **both**. In over 90% of all cases, this is probably what you want.

But there are others:

If you want to material to look like the paint or **glossy part is smooth** and even and **below** that, there is a **bumpy surface** (application example: Wood finish in a car interiour), then add the normal map **only to the diffuse shader** of the shader.

If you want the material to look like it has a smooth general surface but a **slightly scratched paint or top layer**, it might make sense to **only connect it to the glossy shader** (probably the less frequently used case).

[image]

Comment: Hi Julian. I have made a image to test your solution and you are absolutely right. Thank you for your answer!